# ZipEntry returns null from BLOB ZipArchiveInputStream

Tags: java, xml, inputstream, php-ziparchive

Main problem is that I get null result from my zipEntry. What I am doing is getting BLOB.zip from database, directing it to input stream, from there to zipArchiveInputStream and to ZipEntry which returns null every time. I decided to use ZipArchiveInputStream after using ZipInputStream with same null results.

```
public byte[] getXMLStream() {              
    try {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT SAVEDATA FROM JDBEVPP1.TEVP005 WHERE GFNR = 357420", byte[].class); }                                   
    catch(DataAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;}}

@Override
public void getXMLdata() {
    byte[] str = getXMLStream();
     InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(str);
     ZipArchiveInputStream fis = new ZipArchiveInputStream(myInputStream);
     ZipEntry entry = null;
     try { 
         while ( (entry = fis.getNextZipEntry()) != null ) { 
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
         }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I just need to get this xml and print it in console for testing. Any idea what is wrong here or how to make it work?

EDIT:  Inside BLOB is XML format which I need to present on console.

Comment: Save the BLOB stream to a file and use a hey editor to check the magic file header to make sure it is really a ZIP file. Also use zip tools like 7zip to check if the BLOB is a valid compressed archive.

Comment: It seems only mistake was in type of xml. I have used GZIPInputStream and it works.

Comment: GZIP an ZIP are two completely different formats...

Comment: And I did not know that earlier. It was a very good day, I have learned a lot today. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by using GZIPInputStream. It seems it is generic xml at the end..

```
try {
        GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(bys);
        Reader decoder = new InputStreamReader(gzip, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(decoder);
        System.out.println(buffered.readLine());
        String data = buffered.readLine();
        InputSource xml = new InputSource(new StringReader(data));
        System.out.println(xml);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```